# Have any details been released (or leaked) on the Trump-Hifter (=Haftar) call?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, foreign-policy, libya

A NYT article on Libyan civil war [states](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/01/18/world/middleeast/libya-war-hifter-russia.html):

> And the messages from Washington have been mixed. Days after Mr. Pompeo urged Mr. Hifter to stop his assault on Tripoli in April, President Trump called Mr. Hifter to commend him. The next day, Mr. Hifter began shelling civilian neighborhoods of the capital for the first time.

Have any details on the contents of this call between Trump and Hifter (or Haftar as his name spelled elsewhere) been published or leaked to the press?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be [a statement from the White House](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-libya-security-trump/white-house-says-trump-spoke-to-libyan-commander-haftar-on-monday-idUSKCN1RV0WW) itself saying some details:

> A White House statement said that in the phone call on Monday, Trump “recognized Field Marshal Haftar’s significant role in fighting terrorism and securing Libya’s oil resources, and the two discussed a shared vision for Libya’s transition to a stable, democratic political system”.

Though [an unidentified source from inside the White House](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2019-04-24/trump-libya-haftar-tripoli) have called the statement "inaccurate:"

> On Wednesday, after publication of this story, a White House spokesman who declined to be identified said the characterization of the phone calls between Haftar and Trump and Bolton was inaccurate. He didn’t elaborate.

No further details of the contents of call itself (that is, a transcript) have been released or leaked that I am aware of.

Comment: What part of this is a rumor? I'm quoting published sources.

Comment: "Rumor: 2) a statement or report current without known authority for its truth" - https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rumor Seems to me that an an unnamed person stating something that cannot be checked fits that definition. (There is an official statement that contradicts the rumor, so it's even worse than "without known authority for its truth"). The fact that Bloomberg published that rumor, doesn't make it less a rumor.